# Powershell Window Tiny at High Resolution

Tags: powershell, resolution

I have recently bought a Lenovo Yoga 3 ultrabook which has a screen resolution of 3200 x 1800.

My cmd window and Powershell window are tiny at this resolution. I have changed the size of the normal cmd window using the Defaults context menu item (which appears when you click the top left corner of the cmd window). I also changed the font and this made an acceptable window/font size.

However, the Powershell window initially opens at the new size then shrinks to the size you can see in the screen shot  [image: PS screenshot imgur]

How can I rectify this? 
Thanks.

Comment: are you making your changes on the shortcut properties, or in the title bar -> defaults dialog? if you compare the two, do they match?

Comment: @Frank I made the changes in the Defaults dialog. They don't match. When I changed the Properties (item under the Defaults menu item), an error message displayed "Unable to change Shortcut". Then, when I clicked OK, the window grew to the values I set. But they weren't retained when I closed and re-opened the powershell window.

Comment: You might like to use ConEmu instead. It is much better than the standard console.

Answer (score 0):

> I have changed the size of the normal cmd window using the Defaults
>   context menu item (which appears when you click the top left corner of
>   the cmd window). I also changed the font and this made an acceptable
>   window/font size.
>
> However, the Powershell window initially opens at the new size then
>   shrinks to the size you can see in the screen shot

Change the settings and default settings with admin rights.
I would prefer the font `consolas`, i had some trouble with `lucida console`.

And you can change the size in your profile, see variable `$profile`

```
if ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost')
{
    $neededWidth = 210

    $pswindow = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI

    if ($pswindow.WindowSize.Width -ge $neededWidth -and $pswindow.BufferSize.Width -ge $neededWidth)
    {
        Exit 1
    }

    $bufferSizeTemp = $pswindow.BufferSize
    $bufferSizeTemp.Width =  $neededWidth

    $pswindow.BufferSize = $bufferSizeTemp

    $windowsSizeTemp = $pswindow.WindowSize
    $windowsSizeTemp.Width =  $neededWidth

    $pswindow.WindowSize = $windowsSizeTemp
}
```

Comment: Your script has conflicting code.  You set two variables twice to in theory what could be entirely different values.